# How to chain two futures

Tags: java, future, completable-future

My method receives a `CompletableFuture`. It launches another operation that returns a second future. I want the given future to be completed the same way the other future is completed - with the same value or exception.

Currently I'm doing it with `whenComplete` method, but I have a gut feeling that there's a shorter way:

```java
public void m(CompletableFuture f) {
    CompletableFuture fInternal = executeOperation();
    fInternal.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
        if (t != null) {
            f.completeExceptionally(t);
        } else {
            f.complete(r);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this more simply?

Comment: Are you intentionally using **raw types** here? You should specify the generics of the `CompletableFuture` all the time.

Comment: Perhaps your question might get more attention on : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Zabuzard yes, i use raw to focus on the main point. Assume the type argument of both is the same.

Comment: @Thomas how would you use `thenCompose` here?

Comment: @Eugene you're right, thinking once more about it those methods wouldn't help.

Comment: The code you're using looks to be as concise as it can be (you could make it shorter using a ternary but that's not a point). Since your code doesn't return a future that basically combines the results of bot but binds `f` to `fInternal` you'd need to listen for the completion of `fInternal` and then act on the result. However, I'm not sure this approach makes that much sense: what if `f` got completed already and possibly with another result? If that can't happen, then why is `f` a future in the first place? If you want to add callbacks to the result, why not return a future instead?

Comment: what you currently have is perfectly fine. I see not other "simpler" way.